# Trying to check if password contains both letters and numbers with python

Tags: python, passwords, password-checker

I am trying to create python code that checks whether a password is:

Is at least 6 characters long.
Contains both letters and numbers.
Isn't letters only.
Isn't numbers only.

Doesn't use any:
Imported libraries.
Loop Structures.
User defined inputs.

Here is the code:

```
MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6
MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 10
password = input('Enter your Password:\n')
password_length = len(password)

#Do I need the two lines below?
#if (len(password) < 6 or len(password) > 10) :
#    print ("Password is Weak - Doesn't Meet Length Requirements") 

#below code checks input for alphabetical characters
if password.isalpha :
    print ("Password is Weak - Only Contains Letters") 

#below code checks input for numerical characters
elif password.isnumeric :
    print ("Password is Weak - Only Contains Numbers")
#cannot get it to recognise numbers inputed into password field, mistakes numbers for letters

#below code checks input for both alphabetical and numerical characters
elif password.isalnum :
    print ("Password is Strong")
```

I need help with this (am I missing something?), any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Alphanumeric means that a string contains only letters and numbers, not that a string must contain _both_ letters and numbers. Please update either the title or the question to reflect this distinction.

Comment: updated title and question, hopefully it clears things up

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def is_valid_alphanumeric_password(password):
    if not re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,10}$', password):
        return False

    return True
```

This is a basic code for the check and re or regular expression library is pre-installed it checks for all the condition and returns **True** or **False** based on it.

Comment: This answer fails for `password='0123456789'` and `password='foobar'`. Arguably the title doesn't match the actual question, but it seems clear that a password which meets the length requirement and is only letters or only digits is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

It actually sounds like your accepted password should have a length of 6 to 10 characters *and* should contain *both* numbers and letters:

```py
def is_valid_alphanumeric_password(password):
    if not re.search(r'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-z0-9]{6,10}$', password, flags=re.I):
        return False

    return True

print(is_valid_alphanumeric_password("abcdef"))  # False
print(is_valid_alphanumeric_password("123456"))  # False
print(is_valid_alphanumeric_password("abc123"))  # True
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `^` from the start of the password

  - `(?=.*[a-z])` assert that at least one letter (any case) occurs
  - `(?=.*[0-9])` assert that at least one digit occurs
  - `[a-z0-9]{6,10}` then match 6 to 10 alphanumeric characters
- `$` end of the password

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the code

```
 password = input('Enter your Password: ')

 if password.isalpha():
    print ("Password is Weak - Only Contains Letters") 
    
 elif password.isnumeric():
    print ("Password is Weak - Only Contains Numbers")
    
 else: 
    print ("Password is Strong")
```

Didn't need the following code

```
 MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6
 MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 10
 password_length = len(password)
```

forgot to add () after isnumeric & isalpha